# Angular reactive form set validators on control change

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form and I want to change *password* and *confirm password* `validators` when I change the password value. I´m subscribing to password control `valueChanges` and setting the `validators` when the control value changes. To avoid repeating the operation just once, I unsubscribed after setting `validators`.

The problem is that the validators are set correctly but once all fields get completed, although there is no error in the form, but it is marked as `invalid`.

I have tried setting the `validators` outside the subscription to the `valueChanges` and it works properly.

I tried using a function that returns the controls that have errors but no error was returned once I completed all fields as expected.

I don´t know why it doesn't work properly.

**Form code:**

```js
 this.form = this.fb.group({
     usuario: [this.data.usuario, [Validators.required]],
     password: [this.data.password, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
     confirmarPassword: [{ value: '', disabled: true }],
     nombre: [this.data.nombre, [Validators.required]],
     apellido: [this.data.apellido, [Validators.required]],
     inicial: [this.data.inicial, [Validators.required]],
     email: [this.data.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
     habilitado: [this.data.habilitado.value],
     imagenPerfil: [this.data.imagenPerfil, null],
     modoNuevoPerfil: [false],
     modoEditarPerfil: [false],
     permisos: this.fb.group({
         nombre: ['', null],
         usuarios: this.fb.group({
             alta: [false],
             baja: [false],
             modificacion: [false],
             visualizacion: [false]
         }),
         usuariosPerfiles: this.fb.group({
             alta: [false],
             baja: [false],
             modificacion: [false],
             visualizacion: [false]
         }),
         configuracionesTecnicas: this.fb.group({
             alta: [false],
             baja: [false],
             modificacion: [false],
             visualizacion: [false]
         }),
         drogas: this.fb.group({
             alta: [false],
             baja: [false],
             modificacion: [false],
             visualizacion: [false]
         }),
         drogasCertificados: this.fb.group({
             alta: [false],
             baja: [false],
             visualizacion: [false]
         }),
         drogasRetesteos: this.fb.group({
             alta: [false],
             baja: [false],
             modificacion: [false],
             aprobarRechazar: [false],
             visualizacion: [false]
         }),
         drogasMovimientos: this.fb.group({
             alta: [false],
             baja: [false],
             modificacion: [false],
             visualizacion: [false]
         }),
         soluciones: this.fb.group({
             alta: [false],
             baja: [false],
             modificacion: [false],
             aprobarRechazar: [false],
             visualizacion: [false]
         }),
         equiposAuxiliares: this.fb.group({
             alta: [false],
             baja: [false],
             modificacion: [false],
             visualizacion: [false]
         }),
         equiposAuxiliaresCertificados: this.fb.group({
             alta: [false],
             baja: [false],
             modificacion: [false],
             visualizacion: [false]
         }),
         materialVolumetrico: this.fb.group({
             alta: [false],
             baja: [false],
             modificacion: [false],
             visualizacion: [false]
         }),
         materialVolumetricoCertificados: this.fb.group({
             alta: [false],
             baja: [false],
             modificacion: [false],
             visualizacion: [false]
         }),
     })
 });
```

**Value changes subscription code:**

```js
this.passwordChange$ = this.form.controls.usuario.valueChanges.subscribe(
    () => {
        this.form.setValidators(this.passwordCoinciden('password', 'confirmarPassword'));
        this.form.controls.confirmarPassword.enable()
        this.form.controls.confirmarPassword.setValidators([Validators.required]);
        this.form.updateValueAndValidity()
        this.passwordChange$.unsubscribe()
    }
)
```

**Function to check errors code:**

```js
 function findInvalidControls() {
     const invalid = [];
     const controls = this.form.controls;
     for (const name in controls) {
         if (controls[name].invalid) {
             invalid.push(name);
         }
     }
     return invalid;
 }
```

Comment: why not forget remove/add validators and use some like `confirmarPassword: [value: '', [this.passwordCoinciden('password', 'confirmarPassword'),Validators.required]`. Remember that a FormControl disabled is not checked -it's always valid-. BTW, what's the aim of disabled `comfirmarPassword`?

Comment: Are you sure your form is still listening after the first changes ? Because you unsubscribe just at the end so it will listen the first time then stop listening and so this code will never be executed again

Comment: @ Eliseo. This form is inside a dialog that when is opened to add a new user it works properly. When I open it for editing an existing user y load all fetched user data but i do not need to validate the password until it is modified. That is why I disable `confirmarPassword`. @Lud I have tried both approaches unsubscribing an not unsubscribing. The idea of unsubscribing was that once the validators are set that code is not executed again.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a post regarding RF and custom validator functions, you can find some examples

https://dev.to/salimchemes/reactiveforms-formarrays-and-custom-validators-1d0k

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to solve this, i do not understand why it works this why but still this could help some one.

Set my cumstom validator when the form is initialized but keep my `confirmarPassword` disabled so the validation is not checked.

Then I subscribe to `this.form.controls.password.valueChanges` and when it changes i enable `confirmarPassword`

So as I said i do not know why but the the form validators do not work as expected if you set them inside a formControl valueChanges observable.

**Form Code:**

```
         this.form = this.fb.group({
         usuario: [this.data.usuario, [Validators.required]],
         password: [this.data.password, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
         confirmarPassword: [{ value: '', disabled: true }],
         nombre: [this.data.nombre, [Validators.required]],
         apellido: [this.data.apellido, [Validators.required]],
         inicial: [this.data.inicial, [Validators.required]],
         email: [this.data.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
         habilitado: [this.data.habilitado.value],
         imagenPerfil: [this.data.imagenPerfil, null],
         modoNuevoPerfil: [false],
         modoEditarPerfil: [false],
     });
// Here I set the validator but it does not work until I enable 'confirmarPassword'
    this.form.setValidators(this.passwordCoinciden('password', 'confirmarPassword'));
```

**Value Changes Subscription Code:**

```
this.passwordChange$ = this.form.controls.usuario.valueChanges.subscribe(
    () => {
        this.form.controls.confirmarPassword.setValidators([Validators.required]);
        this.form.controls.confirmarPassword.enable()
        this.form.updateValueAndValidity()
        this.passwordChange$.unsubscribe();
    }
)
```

**UPDATE 9/7/2020**

I found that the problem was in my custom validator i was using incorrectly the ValidatorFn interfase because i was returning an empty object when there was no error instead of null.

**MODIFIED CUSTOM VALIDATOR CODE**

```
passwordCoinciden(_password: string, _confirmarPassword: string) : ValidatorFn{
return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
  let password = group.controls[_password];
  let confirmarPassword = group.controls[_confirmarPassword];

  if (password.value && confirmarPassword.value && password.value != confirmarPassword.value ) {
    this.form.controls[_confirmarPassword].markAllAsTouched()
    this.form.controls[_confirmarPassword].setErrors({passNoCoinciden: "Los passwords no coinciden" })
    return {passNoCoinciden: "Los passwords no coinciden" }
           
  } else {
  this.form.controls[_confirmarPassword].setErrors(null);
   return  null
  } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    phonenumber: [""],
    check: [false]
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm.get("check").valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      if (value) {
        this.loginForm.get("phonenumber").setValidators([Validators.required]);
      } else {
        this.loginForm.get("phonenumber").clearValidators();
      }
      this.loginForm.get("phonenumber").updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent : false });
      console.log(this.loginForm.valid);
    });
  }

  loginUser() {}
}
```

you can test it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aeuwgr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

For those who get an error saying "MaxExecutionStack..." be aware, that this is because

```
emitEvent : false
```

option inside `updateValueAndValidity` method!